# Adding a County input field into Address in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Any ideas how to add custom fields to the address Model?

I want to add a free text input for County, so that it can be used for the equivalent in any country, as the shop sells to more than UK.

Upon doing so, I get the following error when trying to edit an address;

```
Craft\Commerce_AddressModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "county".
```

Comment: There's no UI for this in the control panel since addresses aren't an element type.  Did you get that error in the context of a plugin where you tried to extend the existing `Commerce_AddressModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Dec '16) I have managed to get around this by re-using the Region/State field and passing this information through as a text field input that the user can enter.

```
<label class="label" for="{{ modelName }}-stateName">County</label>
<input type="text" id="{{ modelName }}-stateName" name="{{ modelName }}[stateName]" value="{{ model.stateName}}">
```

This ensures that the County is saved in the address model. It can be access as per any other address field in the templates.

I set the back-end has all States/Regions to be empty. But the user-entered text field is still stored against each customer saved address or order billing/shipping addresses.

The only downfall at the moment, is that in the back-end this is stored out-of order in terms of a structured UK address. The system stores this AFTER the postcode/zip code field.
So an address format looks like this;
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Town/City
Postcode
Region
Country

Rather than

Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Town/City
Region 
Postcode
Country

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Dec '16) - custom fields are not able to be used with addresses in Commerce.

Your best best is probably to add a field to your orders and pretend it's on addresses, but obviously if you deal with multiple addresses, as you probably do, that gets a bit tricky quickly.  You could implement a plugin that has it's own table of records that associate addressIDs with a county field.

I am pretty sure it's on the Commerce radar but you're a bit stuck right now I think, without some extra work.

Comment: I think I might have to make it work for UK county using the regions field and hide this away/disable for other EU countries.

Comment: You could also put all in for all countries (UK - Suffolk for example) and filter on the front end by country